# regex returns first and last match instead of returning first and second match inbetween matching parenthesis

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-2.7

I am trying to parse text to extract desired strings. I am missing something in the `regex`, can someone help me figure out what is the issue here?

This is my script:

```
import re
a = """
    block1
          #(/*AUTOINSTPARAM*/
        // Parameters
        .THREE          (3),     // comment
        .TWO            (2), // comment
        .ONE    (1))             // comment
        inst1
           (/*AUTOINST*/
        // extra
        // output

    block2
          #(/*AUTOINSTPARAM*/
        // Parameters
        .THREE          (3),     // comment
        .TWO            (2), // comment
        .ONE    (1))             // comment
        inst2
           (/*AUTOINST*/
        // extra
        // output
"""

op = re.findall(r'(\w+)\s*(#\(.*\))?.*?(\w+)\s*\(', a, re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
for i in op:
    print(i[0],i[2])
```

This is the output:

```
('block1', 'inst2')
```

Expected output:

```
('block1', 'inst1')
('block2', 'inst2')
```

Updated:
Trying to test following input for the same regex as accepted answer:

```
import re
a = """
    except_check
          #(
            .a        (m),
            .b        (w),
            .c        (x),
            .d        (1),
            .e        (1)
        )
        data_check
           (// Outputs

  abc
  #(
    .a                          (b::c)
   )
   mask
   (/*AUTOINST*/

"""

op = re.findall(r'^\s*(\w+)\s*$\n(?:^\s*[#/.].*$\n)*^\s*(\w+)\s*\(', a, re.MULTILINE)
for i in op:
    print(i)
```

It did not return anything. It should have returned following:

```
('except_check', 'data_check')
('abc', 'mask')
```

Comment: If you have a new question, ask a new question, or unaccept the answer you accepted if it's not acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
#op = re.findall(r'^\s*(\w+)\s*$\n(?:^\s*[#/.].*$\n)*^\s*(\w+)\s*\(', a, re.MULTILINE)
op = re.findall(r'^\s*(\w+)\s*$\n(?:^\s*[^\w\s].*$\n)*^\s*(\w+)\s*\(', a, re.MULTILINE)
for i in op:
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
('block1', 'inst1')
('block2', 'inst2')
```

- `^\s*(\w+)\s*$\n` matches the blockname line
- `(?:^\s*[^\w\s].*$\n)*` matches the parameter lines
- `^\s*(\w+)\s*\(` matches the instance name line

Please note I have disabled the `re.DOTALL` option (although it is trivial to solve this problem).

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked like a charm!

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Good to know it works.

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/8572380/tshiono
I am trying to use the same regex for this input:

except_check
          #(
            .a                       (m),
            .b                      (w),
            .c                     (x),
            .d                  (1),
            .e        (1)
        )
        data_check
           (// Outputs
but couldn't get the desired output ('except_check', ' data_check'). Any idea why?

Comment: In my environment it also works fine. Can you post the input not in the comment but adding to your question to preserve the line breaks and indents. Then I will test with it as well.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I've modified my regex according to your input. The older one is left with commented out just as a reference.

Comment: The reason why the previous one did not work is I did not consider the case a line starts with a parenthesis. Now it is fixed. The regex `[^\w\s]` matches a special character including '#', '/', '.', '(' and ')'.

Comment: Thank you so much! Really appreciate your clean answer!

Comment: My pleasure. I thank you too for the courtesy.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `.*` matching as *much* as possible (greedy) and with `re.DOTALL` it will match your entire string leavig as little as neccessary to still match *at all*.

```
(\w+)\s*(#\(.*\))?.*?(\w+)\s*\(
            ^^ this one
```

Basically any regex with `.*` (if `.` is allowed to capture truly everything) will only match once or not at all, since it is capable of matching anything the rest of the rexpression could aswell.

Just using `.*?` wont fix this either, because:

Another issue with the string are the brackets. Regex (without some fancy extensions) is only capable of matching brackets with finite nesting. Assuming a maximum nesting-depth of 2 in the `AUTOINSTPARAM` block, the following regex would work:

```
vvvvv blockX                                    vvvvv instX
(\w+)\s*(#\([^(]*(\([^)]*\)[^()]*)*\))?[^\n]*\s*(\w+)\s*\(
                  ^^inner^^
          ^^ outer bracket         ^^
```

These `[^()]` groups are there instad of `.` to prevent it from eating any broken brackets by just ignoring them. If you know more about the format you could narrow this down even more.

Also note that this regex assumes the comment between the last `)` and `instX` matches `[^\n]*\s*` and it will accept anything that is not a bracket inside brackets.

Comment: It doesn't work for me as parameters are not fixed and I need to have all the parameters as optional in regex.

Comment: But the parameters are completely ignored by the regex. the outer-bracket part will consume anything between the `#(/*AUTO...` and `)     //comment`.

Answer (score 0):

If the word characters for the second group are after 2 closing parenthesis, you can omit the `re.DOTALL` and use for example a pattern that stretches over multiple lines using `[\s\S]*?` matching as least as possible until you encounter 2 consecutive parenthesis.

This pattern is based on the example data, and can be error prone as it depends on 2 parenthesis as the last part before block 2.

```
^\s*(\w+)\r?\n\s*#\([\s\S]*?\)\s*\).*\r?\n\s*(\w+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kFPMIj/1)

Another option could be matching the lines after the first block that do not start with a word character, and that capture in group 2 the word characters of the line that does.

```
^\s*(\w+)\r?\n[^\S\r\n]*#\(.*(?:\r?\n(?![^\S\r\n]*\w).*)*\r?\n[^\S\r\n]+(\w+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kgP8ye/1)